# QuestionAdding a 'Flag as Inappropriate' flag to comments on a SharePoint blog

Tags: sharepoint

I am sorry if this has been asked before, but a google search of stackoverflow didn't find anything relevant.

We are about to pilot blogging within our organisation and as part of compliance we require every comment left on a blog to have a link associated with it for users to flag the comment as inappropriate.

My thinking is that this link could simply change the comment's status from approved to pending and possible send an email to the approvers to go and check it.

By default we need comments to not need pre-approval.

Could anyone please explain the different ways of achieving this? Is there a way of achieving this using SharePoint settings (i.e. no code)?

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to have approve/reject only when users flagged/report that comment ..

it is possible to do with sharepoint designer without any code or coding

you should define a workflow that if creator same as modifier approved automatically and when someone edit or flagged as blob ... change that item status to suspend and workflow not fired. because that condition is not true. and modifier and creator different people